# SOAPUI execute groovy script from command line

Tags: batch-file, soapui

I wrote batch script which executes soapui from command line. It does sth like Launch LoadTestRunner and generates reports in indicated folder. 
In my Test Steps I need to change dates in specific nodes on tomorrows date. I wrote groovy script which works fine in soapui but I can't load it from batch script.

My question is: is there a possibility to run tests from the console (batch script) but first run groovy script which will change dates in the same batch script?

My groovy script:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.*

def ui = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project

def testSuite = project.getTestSuiteAt(0)
def testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseAt(0)

//set date  
def today = new Date()
def dd = today.getDate() + 1
def mm = today.getMonth() + 1  //January is 0!
def yyyy = 1900 + today.getYear()

if (dd < 10)   dd = '0' + dd
if (mm < 10)  mm = '0' + mm

tomorrowsDateAndTime = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd  + "+01:00"

//xml paths to change date
def somePathToChangeDate = "//somePathToChangeDate"
def somePathToChangeDate2 = "//somePathToChangeDate2"

def stepList = testCase.getTestStepList() //list of all tests in package

for (singleTest in stepList) {
    log.info("          " + singleTest.getName())
    def testName = singleTest.getName()
    testSuite.setPropertyValue("testName",  testName)
    def testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName(testName)
    def testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(testStepContext) 
    def inputHolder = testName + "#Request"
    def holderRawReq = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(inputHolder)    

    holderRawReq[somePathToChangeDate] = tomorrowsDateAndTime
    holderRawReq[somePathToChangeDate2] = tomorrowsDateAndTime

    holderRawReq.updateProperty()
}
log.info "          Dates are updated"
```

My batch script:

```
@echo off

cd %~dp0\SoapUI-5.2\bin

cmd.exe /C loadtestrunner.bat -s"TestSuite 1" -cmyTests -l"LoadTest 1" -uusername -ppassword -r -f%~dp0\reports %~dp0\my-soapui-project.xml


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" %~dp0\Reports\LoadTest_1-log.txt| find /C ":""

::this code checks if there are any error reports
for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set iterator=%%a
echo %iterator%
cls

if [%iterator%] equ [3] (echo "Tests was completed successfully") else ( 

    echo "Tests failed"
 )

pause
```

Comment: Can you not use `setup script`?

Comment: @Rao you're right `: )` surely `setup script` in the `testSuite` can do the trick, however I need to read various times your comment to understand what did you mean (maybe it's due to my broken english)... but if you expand a bit more it can help the OP to figure it `; )`

Comment: Sorry about being cryptic @albciff, which is not intentional. Will keep it in mind, and thank you for the constructive feedback.

Comment: @Rao albciff Thanks for your answers, I used `setup script` like you recommended but error occured: 
`java.lang.nullpointerexception cannot get property 'testsuite' on null object`

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the script that was put in setup script?  By the way, are you using setup script of what level, is it testsuite or test case level?

Comment: Level testsuite, I put in `setup script` exacly the same script as above in my question.

Comment: In testcase level the same error occured